# SystemParametersInfo and ERROR_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, screensaver, usermode

I'm coding this user-mode executable that can be run from a local service on a Windows platform in a context of logged in users. Its main purpose is to configure a desktop of all logged in users. It calls the following API to set up screensaver:

```
if(!SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, nTimeoutSec, 0, 0))
{
    //Error
    GetLastError();
}

if(!SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE, nActive, 0, 0))
{
    //Error
    GetLastError();
}
```

The code above works in most cases, except at times when I have more than one user logged on to the Windows console I get this weird error ERROR_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS. I looked up the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it has this explanation:

> If the machine has entered power saving mode or system lock state, an
>   ERROR_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS exception occurs.

OK, but how shall I treat this error?

PS. This happens most often on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

`SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE` can produce some error and do nothing. Try to send a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `SC_SCREENSAVE` message to the `GetDesktopWindow()` window.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but at this point I can't emulate that condition... Any idea when exactly that error is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it looks like this is actually not possible with Windows 8+, although its not explicitly stated on MSDN.

## My Research

It does state on another MSDN article for [SetThreadExecutionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208(v=vs.85).aspx) that on Windows 8 the *ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED* flag does not wake the screen.

> Windows 8:  This flag can only keep a display turned on, it can't turn on a display that's currently off.

There is an API call for removing the active screensaver ([SPI_SETSCREENSAVEACTIVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx)) does state the following:

> If the machine has entered power saving mode or system lock state, an ERROR_OPERATION_IN_PROGRESS exception occurs

## Conclusion

The system was not in a lock state AND not in power saving mode (using [GUID_MIN_POWER_SAVINGS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372758(v=vs.85).aspx)), so it seems Windows 8+ machines cannot wake the screen.